# SpriteKit: Change color of part of sprite which is intersecting with another sprite

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have two `SKSpriteNodes` which are basic rectangles with solid colors (red and blue).

When users drags them around. I want to check if the two nodes are intersecting and change the color of the part of first node which is intersecting with the second node.

I am able to tell if the nodes are intersecting by using `.intersects(..)` property of node.

But I  cant figure out how to get the actual intersection area and how to color that part of node different from its original color.

Comment: Nothing that is built in and can solve the issue. You should do your own calculations of intersection area. Or maybe you could try playing with blendMode on sprites...

Answer (score 2):

It can get a little funky, but after your nodes pass the intersect check:

```
//Note: I am assuming both frames are on the same parent node, you may need to convert if parents are different

let intersection = sprite1.frame.intersection(sprite2.frame)
```

We now have the intersection rect, so let's make a color sprite

```
let miniSprite = SKSpriteNode(color:.red,size:intersection.size) 
miniSprite.alpha = 0.5
```

add it to the scene

```
sprite1.parent.addChild(miniSprite)
```

set the position

```
miniSprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0,y:0.0)
miniSprite.position = intersection.origin
```

move it to sprite1 (This will convert the position for us)

```
miniSprite.move(toParent:sprite1)
```

We now have a boxed area that is a different color.

But our sprite is not a square? You may ask.

Well this is where `SKCropNode` comes in.

Let's make a crop node.

```
let croppedNode = SKCropNode()
```

We want to add our sprite1 as the mask node

```
croppedNode.maskNode = sprite1.copy() as? SKNode
```

Then add this to the sprite1 as a child
    sprite1.addChild(croppedNode)

We now have a crop node with a mask of our sprite, let us move our mini node to this new cropped node

```
miniSprite.move(toParent:croppedNode)
```

There we go, you should now have a color where intersection happens.

The final code should look like this:

```
let intersection = sprite1.frame.intersection(sprite2.frame)
let miniSprite = SKSpriteNode(color:.red,size:intersection.size) 
miniSprite.alpha = 0.5
sprite1.parent!.addChild(miniSprite)
miniSprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0,y:0.0) 
miniSprite.position = intersection.origin
let croppedNode = SKCropNode()
croppedNode.maskNode = sprite1.copy() as? SKNode
croppedNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0.5)
sprite1.addChild(croppedNode)
miniSprite.move(toParent:croppedNode)
```

Now somethings to keep in mind,

zPosition may need to get adjusted

Here is example of it working:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let sprite1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
    sprite1.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0.5)
    sprite1.position = CGPoint.zero
    sprite1.zPosition = 1



    let sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
    sprite2.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0.5)
    sprite2.position = CGPoint(x:0,y:300)
    addChild(sprite1)
    addChild(sprite2)

    let intersection = sprite1.frame.intersection(sprite2.frame)
    let miniSprite = SKSpriteNode(color:.red,size:intersection.size)
    miniSprite.alpha = 0.5

    miniSprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0,y:0.0)
    miniSprite.position = intersection.origin
    miniSprite.zPosition = 2
    sprite1.parent!.addChild(miniSprite)
    let croppedNode = SKCropNode()
    croppedNode.maskNode = sprite1.copy() as? SKNode
    croppedNode.zPosition = 3
    sprite1.addChild(croppedNode)

    let biggy = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: (scene?.size)!)
    miniSprite.move(toParent:croppedNode)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if this actually works or if there are changes that I need to make.

Comment: Wow, very elaborate answer. I am working on a different project now but when I get back to this, I will definitely try this and accept your answer if it works or let you if it doesn't.

Comment: lol well I gave you a proof it works, if it doesn't you are not doing something correctly.